thunderstorm seen from ISS shader for surfaces

can you give a hand (some tutorial, shader editor diagram snip, or other stuff, to give a solution) to not proffesional blender user, how to create thunderstorm shader for flat surfaces/areas like we would see it from ISS. I mean random point lights (emiters) appearing on a surface with some blast/flash areas around it - just like white flashes seen ona gif here.
more samples here
https://images.app.goo.gl/dPj4LCijJBeH8nuy5
thanks in advance
cheers

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

What have you tried as far?

i have tried multiplying noise textures to generate points, but effect is very poor

Multiplying noise textures is definitely a step in the right direction. I tried to give some answer, maybe someone else can get a better result.

The solution I have is far from perfect, but maybe that's something you can work with. It basically comes down to this: I have an animated Noise Texture for the lightning multiplied by an animated Voronoi Texture to determine the spots where the lightning appears. The drivers for the animation are the frame numbers divided by some values which depend on what you think is looking good.
I just played around a bit with the values, there is a lot of room for tweaking to change the result like the size of the lightning areas and how often the lightning flashes (by changing the Scale of the Voronoi Texture and settings of its Color Ramp) and the duration of the lightning (by changing the frame divisor for the W value of the Voronoi Texture) or how "active" the lightning area is (by changing the Scale of the Noise Texture and the frame divisor for its W value).
This is the pure Noise Texture, it is set to 4D to animate the W value, the fame number gets divided by 100 and the texture Scale is 50:

And this is the output of the Voronoi Texture, the frame number divided by 150 (the Add node is there to have some kind of seed variation), the Scale is set to 3 and the Color Ramp narrows down the texture to small circles:

The complete material setup looks like this, the Noise Texture and Voronoi Texture get multiplied so that the noise only appears where the Voronoi circles are. The result I multiplied with 100 for the Strength of an Emission shader. Then I used an Add Shader to add the emission to a Transparent BSDF. I do not use a Mix Shader to avoid semi-transparent areas.

For a quick example how the end result looks like, I place the lightning plane above a plane with some satellite image of earth (the resolution is not very high, especially the city lights) and inbetween two planes with cloud layers:

The animation looks like this (sorry I had to reduce the size and quality a lot to be able to upload it here). The lightning plane determines the area where the "thunderstorm" is happening, of course you can change its size and shape to whatever you need.



Nice one, cool results. There is something weirdly relaxing about watching distant thunder

man, this is brilliant. Looks very good

i just noticed you used cycles, but can it work in evee?

Seems when i omit emmission node it is visible in evee, but without light source and without transparency. How to alternate cycles here?
Anyway, its an impressive job you have done, clearly know what you're doing. Respect

@Mrsudzio Oh, it wasn't clear from the question you want to use Eevee. Transparency works there if you set it up correctly in the material properties, with the Blend Mode set to Alpha Hashed or Alpha Blend (plenty of questions here on this topic if you search for it). But the thing is, the light from emissive materials does not interact with the environment in Eevee. You would have to use point lights, but not a material. Don't  know if Emission works different in Eevee Next in the upcoming version 4.2, we usually limit answers to official stable releases here.
